# Identify the row in a group that has the highest value and extract all rows in that share its name in Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file that has data arranged like such:

```
       Letter  Subject    Score
    0    A     Knitting    78
    1    A     Knitting    60
    2    A     Knitting    42
    3    B     Knitting    30
    4    B     Knitting    48
    5    C     Diving      23
    6    C     Diving      56
    7    C     Diving      23
    8    D     Diving      78
    ......
```

What I want to do is the following after reading the CSV into Pandas:

- Sort the rows by the score heading
- Group them by Subject
- Identify the letter that has the highest score value in each subject group.
- Remove all rows that have the letter.

1 and 2 I can do, but 3 and 4 together I cannot wrap my head around. Can someone experienced with Pandas shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
df[~df['Letter'].isin(df.set_index('Letter').groupby('Subject')['Score'].idxmax())]
Out: 
  Letter   Subject  Score
3      B  Knitting     30
4      B  Knitting     48
5      C    Diving     23
6      C    Diving     56
7      C    Diving     23
```

`df.set_index('Letter').groupby('Subject')['Score'].idxmax()` returns the letter with the highest score for each subject group. I needed to set the index as letter temporarily to get the letter instead of the index. The output of this is:

```
df.set_index('Letter').groupby('Subject')['Score'].idxmax()
Out: 
Subject
Diving      D
Knitting    A
Name: Score, dtype: object
```

Now with boolean indexing, you can select the rows whose corresponding letter is not in the list `['D', 'A']` by using `Series.isin`.